# ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.6/bcrypt/_bcrypt.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_FromLong - - -

Tags: python, odoo-13

I installed pysftp using `pip install pysftp` command in linux server to utilize this library in my odoo13 module. But after installing i am facing this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 87, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 424, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 315, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/module.py", line 404, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/odoo/custom/addons/hr_zk_attendance/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/odoo/custom/addons/hr_zk_attendance/models/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import zk_machine
  File "/odoo/custom/addons/hr_zk_attendance/models/zk_machine.py", line 62, in <module>
    import pysftp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 91, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 37, in <module>
    from paramiko.pkey import PKey
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 31, in <module>
    import bcrypt
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from bcrypt import _bcrypt
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.6/bcrypt/_bcrypt.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_FromLong
2022-07-13 13:30:00,117 6671 INFO visiomate_test werkzeug: 139.135.36.87 - - [13/Jul/2022 13:30:00] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 - 10 0.003 0.288
2022-07-13 13:30:00,122 6671 ERROR visiomate_test werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 258, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/server.py", line 440, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1288, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1258, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 766, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 1457, in dispatch
    odoo.registry(db).check_signaling()
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/__init__.py", line 104, in registry
    return modules.registry.Registry(database_name)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 63, in __new__
    return cls.new(db_name)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 87, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 424, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 315, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 182, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/modules/module.py", line 404, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('odoo.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/odoo/custom/addons/hr_zk_attendance/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import models
  File "/odoo/custom/addons/hr_zk_attendance/models/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import zk_machine
  File "/odoo/custom/addons/hr_zk_attendance/models/zk_machine.py", line 62, in <module>
    import pysftp
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pysftp/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 91, in <module>
    from paramiko.dsskey import DSSKey
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/dsskey.py", line 37, in <module>
    from paramiko.pkey import PKey
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 31, in <module>
    import bcrypt
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from bcrypt import _bcrypt
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.6/bcrypt/_bcrypt.so: undefined symbol: PyInt_FromLong - - -
```

Done a lot of R&D on this issue switch virtual environment from 2.7 to 3.6 but nothing worked to resolve this issue.

- Python version - 3.6.9
- Pip version - 20.3.4

Comment: This is most likely a mismatch between system (/usr) and local (/usr/local) and perhaps even the nonstandard /odoo installs. Without access to the system, it's really hard to diagnose. What I would do is to try to reproduce the issue from a clean base image using Docker. If that works, you not only have a working dev environment but also the proof that something in your local env is messed up.

Comment: Try a different version for pysftp, I think the version that python3.6 supported is not the latest one, can you install lower version of pysftp?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Yes its python version issue as odoo13 requires 3.6 and their pip was active on python 2.7 i link it to 3.6 but now everything is so messed up some are working on 2.7 some require to be install as standard. fresh server initiation in progress maybe to change my approach will share in answer if my issue is resolved

Comment: @Saumilgauswami yes i tried two version 2.9 (latest) and 2.8(explicitly mentioned) during pip installation. No i was following the documentation PyPi mention programming language mentioned in it was 3.5 i think. Currently working on workaround to avoid using these libraries and preferably use standard libraries of python 3.6